# Formula output in knitr inline chunk

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I want to write a reproducible paper in social science using knitr. So I want to print the Fit-Indices of a confirmatory factor analysis inline, using knitr inline chunks.

My minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Run a lavaan model

<<lavaanmodel>>=
library(lavaan)
## cfa model from help
HS.model <- ' visual  =~ x1 + x2 + x3
              textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
              speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9 '

cfaout <- cfa(HS.model, data=HolzingerSwineford1939)
@

Specifiy a fitprintfunction

<<fpf_def>>=
fpf_la <- function(x){  fm_tmp <- fitmeasures(x)

                        cat("\\chi^2 = ", fm_tmp[c("chisq")],
                            ", df = ",    fm_tmp[c("df")],
                            ", RMSEA = ", fm_tmp[c("rmsea")],
                            ", CFI = ",   fm_tmp[c("cli")],
                            ", TLI = ",   fm_tmp[c("tli")],
                            ", SRMR = ",  fm_tmp[c("srmr")],
                            sep = "")}
@

Print the fit inline:\\

The specified model resulted in good model fit $\Sexpr{fpf_la(cfaout)}$

\end{document}
```

The Problem: `$\Sexpr{fpf_la(cfaout)}$` results in nothing.
I guess the handling of non numeric output in inline chunks lead to the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function used in `\Sexpr` should *return* the output. Your function prints it.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
showSquare <- function(x) {
  return(sprintf("%s^2 = %s", x, x^2))
}
@

Let's square 42: $\Sexpr{showSquare(42)}$.

\end{document}
```